# CodeSnippet display from right to left problem

Tags: javascript, django, ckeditor

hello i'm using ckiditor and i use CodeSnippet inside it
it display from right to left
like this https://dzblog.pythonanywhere.com/media/Images/Screenshot_2019-01-21_jkgjfghfghfghfghfghfghfgh1.png

and inside my base.html
i set

```
 <body class = 'rtl'>
   <!-- content-->
 </body>
```

i know but website use 'AR' as default language

so can someone help me to make just CodeSnippet show from left to right

thank you

and this is where ckeditor impact (article.html)

```
<div class="col-lg-10">

<p class="h6 pr3 " style="border-bottom: 2px #eee solid ; padding-bottom: 3em;direction: ltr !important;">
    {{art.body|safe}}

</p>

<p class="lead" style="margin-top: 4em;">  source <span style="color: #32234b">{{art.source}}</span></p>

</div>
```

model.py

```
 class articles(models.Model):
     article_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     avatar = models.ForeignKey(author, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
     likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes', blank=True)


     title = models.CharField('العنوان', max_length=200)
     image = models.ImageField('صورة مناسبة', upload_to = 'Images')
     taker_image = models.CharField('ملتقط الصورة', max_length=200)
     source = models.CharField('المصدر', max_length=200)
     body = RichTextUploadingField('المقال',  blank = True, null = False, config_name = 'special',
                                                            extra_plugins=['youtube', 'codesnippet'],
                                                            external_plugin_resources = [(
                                                            'youtube',
                                                            '/media/youtube/youtube/',
                                                            'plugin.js',

                                                                         )],
                                                                    )


     posted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
     updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
```

Comment: for codesnippet div you can change the `direction` to the `ltr`

Comment: i know but where is the div codesnippet

Comment: how you rendering the ckeditor you can apply styling to that div or any html tag in which you are rendering that ckeditor. or else you provide link or some demo where i can check and tell you where to apply the style.

Comment: i add article.html to see it

Comment: you can add `styling` to `p` with `class="lead"` as i am assuming from your code that ckeditor is rendering inside that `p` tag

Comment: It does not work tried it

Comment: can you share the css code you tried. if possible provide the demo that will help more to solve the issue.

Comment: thank you i add code element to mycss  code{
  direction: ltr !important;
  text-align: left !important;
} and it work